# How to reverse the bool value if it equals to reverse of it

Tags: c#, boolean

I know it is possible to make it with a two line code but I was wondering if it is possibble to 1 line. I feel like I saw a usage with the ? operator but couldn't find what I am looking for.
Such as,

```
bool val = true;
if (a == true){
a = !val
}
```

edit: changed the sample code

Comment: thanks, would there be a problem is a is alread equal to !val ?

Comment: Thank you very much will do

Comment: Would there be a problem in c# too? I feel like it is not stable or efficient way

Comment: `if (a = val)` should be `if (a == val)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One line

Techinically this is single line:

```
if (a == true) a = !val;
```

If `a` is not nullable then this works too:

```
if(a) a = !val;
```

## ?: operator

I think you may be looking for [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
a = a ? !val : a;
```

The `if` is better.

## `&=` and `|=` operators

For the kind of logic you're doing here `&=` and `|=` operators
may be used.

`&=` and `|=` operators will give you the most concise solution but `if` is arguably easiest to read and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

(a = !val) compares the a to the val and alter the value